# Flutter Web converting bytecode to pdf

Tags: flutter, pdf

I need to get a pdf file from backend, and make it downloadable and visible in client side.
In postman, i can get this file and download, via send and download button.
But i can't find a solution about how to do this in Flutter.
I tried something, heres the code:

```
Future<dynamic> getFile(String fileName) async {
final String _token = GetStorage().read('token');
final uri = Uri.parse(EndPoint.getReceiptFile + fileName);
final headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $_token', 
  'content-type' : 'application/pdf',
  'Charset': 'utf-8'
};

var res = await http.readBytes(uri, headers: headers);
var x = res;
print(x.toString());
return x;

/* final res = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
return res.bodyBytes; */
```

}

GetxController

```
 var res = Uint8List(0).obs;
 var fileLoading = false.obs;

 getReceiptFile(filename) async {
 fileLoading.value = true;
  update();
  res.value = await _walletService.getFile(filename);

  fileLoading.value = false;
  update();
  log(res.toString());
```

}

And UI

```
return Obx(
    () => controller.fileLoading.value
        ? Container()
        : SfPdfViewer.memory(
            controller.res.value,
            onDocumentLoadFailed: (details) {
              log('onDocumentLoadFailed ');
              log('${details.error}');
              log('${details.description}');
              log(' value => ${controller.res.value}');
            },
            key: GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState>(),
            controller: PdfViewerController(),
            initialZoomLevel: 1,
          ),
  );
```

Error message:

```
Error: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 10)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertGeneral (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:50844:19)
at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertChunked (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:50824:19)
at convert._Utf8ConversionSink.new.addSlice (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:50344:43)
at convert._Utf8ConversionSink.new.add (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:50341:12)
at _ConverterStreamEventSink.new.add (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:48251:29)
at [_handleData] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:38885:34)
at _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:40448:11)
at [_sendData] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:33985:22)
at [_add] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:33934:26)
at [_add] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:38850:20)
at _EventSinkWrapper.new.add (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:38796:27)
at _HandlerEventSink.new.add (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:39060:16)
at [_handleData] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:38885:34)
at _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:40448:11)
at [_sendData] (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:33985:22)
at _DelayedData.new.perform (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:37447:28)
at _StreamImplEvents.new.handleNext (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:37557:15)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:37305:16)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
at http://localhost:51232/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

Answer (score 0):

dart io libary

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html

get file link i.e. Link.fromUri

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Link-class.html

Comment: i can't understand, how can i add headers to link.fromUri? I need to send a token for getting file.

Comment: a basic solution would be to add the token as a query parameter to the uri, then capture the token in your backend from the get request received from the frontend